# Disabling the Unprotect button in the Ribbon in excel

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to disable the Unprotect button on the Ribbon in Excel 2013?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why would you need such a thing?

Comment: Thank you @VojtěchDohnal for your time, but this is already solved.

Comment: Then perhaps delete the question or post your solution if there is a good chance it could be useful for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup ramedju's link it really where to start.

You should be able to include XML to deal with the Ribbon.
Something similar to:

[Events not getting fired/executed in combobox in Excel Ribbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34762441/events-not-getting-fired-executed-in-combobox-in-excel-ribbon/34763688#34763688)

So, basically -> create some XML for the Ribbon, and put some VBA in a module to handle / control the Ribbon.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for this help PaulG.